# Observing invalid value inside the loop

Tags: go

I've stumbled on a buggy Golang code that was trying to use mutex to prevent changes to the variables printed in a goroutine:

```
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)

    mutex := new(sync.Mutex)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 10; j++ {
            mutex.Lock()
            go func() {
                fmt.Println(i, j, i + j);
                mutex.Unlock()
            }()
        }
    }
```

It is clear to me that mutex doesn't lock directly, but on the next iteration, when the value has been incremented already. What is not clear is why j variable reaches 10 according to the output:

```
...
0 7 7
0 8 8
0 9 9
1 10 11   <--- isn't supposed to be here
...
1 9 10
2 10 12
...
```

I tried to debug the code and `j = 10` is printed when the outer loop for i increments its value. It looks as if the outer loop was releasing the thread allowing goroutine to execute and see invalid value of 10. Could someone clarify this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

You have data races. The results are undefined.

```
$ go run -race racer.go
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c000016110 by goroutine 7:
  main.main.func1()
      /home/peter/gopath/racer.go:17 +0x7f

Previous write at 0x00c000016110 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/racer.go:14 +0xf1

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/racer.go:16 +0xcd
==================
0 1 1
0 2 2
0 3 3
0 4 4
0 5 5
0 6 6
0 7 7
0 8 8
0 9 9
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c000016108 by goroutine 16:
  main.main.func1()
      /home/peter/gopath/racer.go:17 +0x50

Previous write at 0x00c000016108 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/racer.go:13 +0x140

Goroutine 16 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/racer.go:16 +0xcd
==================
1 10 11
1 1 2
1 2 3
1 3 4
1 4 5
1 5 6
1 6 7
1 7 8
1 8 9
1 9 10
2 10 12
2 1 3
2 2 4
2 3 5
2 4 6
2 5 7
2 6 8
2 7 9
2 8 10
2 9 11
3 10 13
3 1 4
3 2 5
3 3 6
3 4 7
3 5 8
3 6 9
3 7 10
3 8 11
3 9 12
4 10 14
4 1 5
4 2 6
4 3 7
4 4 8
4 5 9
4 6 10
4 7 11
4 8 12
4 9 13
5 10 15
5 1 6
5 2 7
5 3 8
5 4 9
5 5 10
5 6 11
5 7 12
5 8 13
5 9 14
6 10 16
6 1 7
6 2 8
6 3 9
6 4 10
6 5 11
6 6 12
6 7 13
6 8 14
6 9 15
7 10 17
7 1 8
7 2 9
7 3 10
7 4 11
7 5 12
7 6 13
7 7 14
7 8 15
7 9 16
8 10 18
8 1 9
8 2 10
8 3 11
8 4 12
8 5 13
8 6 14
8 7 15
8 8 16
8 9 17
9 10 19
9 1 10
9 2 11
9 3 12
9 4 13
9 5 14
9 6 15
9 7 16
9 8 17
9 9 18
Found 2 data race(s)
exit status 66
$
```

`racer.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)

    mutex := new(sync.Mutex)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 10; j++ {
            mutex.Lock()
            go func() {
                fmt.Println(i, j, i+j)
                mutex.Unlock()
            }()
        }
    }
}
```

[Go: Data Race Detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html)

Comment: I understand that the locking is broken here, but it is still not clear why Go exposes `j=10` while it shouldn't. Main thread should have paused on `Lock()` and goroutine was supposed to print some valid value.

Comment: @damluar The mutex ensures that previous goroutine prints before the main goroutine starts another goroutine. The mutex does not ensure that the goroutine prints before the main goroutine increments `j`.

Answer (score 1):

You have data race, so the results are undefined. Run it with the `-race` option to see.

When you call `mutex.Lock()` inside the loop body first, that doesn't block. Then you launch a goroutine that reads `i` and `j` and the main goroutine continues to the next iteration of the inner loop, and increments `j`. Then calls lock again, which will block until the previous goroutine finishes.

But you already have an unsynchronized access (read and write) to `j`.

Comment: I agree that the code is broken. What's not clear is how 10 can appear in the output. Since we use a single processor, goroutine won't execute until the main function gives up the control. I expected it to happen on Lock() and the value be correct. But it looks like it happens midway.

Comment: @damluar As the first sentence of my answer states: the results are undefined. Don't try to find logic in something that is undefined: any output is possible, including the one you got. There is no output which you can expect, only if you have no data race.

Comment: @damluar Also it doesn't matter if you have GOMAXPROCS set to 1: compilers are allowed to generate code that caches variables if there is no synchronization. [The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem) only guarantees goroutines see updated values if there is proper synchronization (and thus no data race).

Answer (score -1):

Let me to answer why you can get the *impossible* 10 when print `j`.

Because when you use goroutine in a loop, `fmt.Println(i, j, i+j)` race with `i++/j++`, you cannot determine what value exactly when you print out, and if `j` increase to the bound, it's possible to print out 10.

if you want to prevent from this race, you can transfer `i`, `j` as argument values, e.g.

```golang
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 10; j++ {
            go func(a, b, c int) {
                fmt.Println(a, b, c);
            }(i, j, i+j)
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.